# Exception on XamForms Init in UWP app following Prism upgrade

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I upgraded to VS/Xamarin Cycle 7 (4.1.2.18) and all was well with my application.  Then tried to upgrade Prism.Forms to 6.2.0, which in turn upgrades Xam Forms to 2.3.1.114.  My android project continues to work, but the UWP app does not.

I noticed that the UWP app now has an upgraded Prism.Forms (6.2.0), but Prism.Core (6.1.0) and Xamarin.Forms (2.3.0.107) remained unchanged.

On investigation, I find that the UWP app crashes on Xamarin.Forms.Init() with

**FileNotFoundException:
"Could not load file or assembly 'ClrCompression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies"**

Should I force the update of the UWP app to consume the latest Xamarin.Forms and Prism.Core? (I was assuming that it was intentionally left downgraded)

(Side note: As a separate test, I did create a non-Prism Xamarin.Forms app, with latest Xam and XF and the UWP app spins up without issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP needs to have Prism.Core 6.2, Prism.Forms 6.2, Prism.Unity.Forms 6.2, and Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.114.  If you don't have these something went wrong with your upgrade.  You didn't get the correct packages.